# Why did Gunke say, "they literally show him figuring all his powers out"?

Tags: marvel, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse (2018)*, Gunke and Miles are watching a Spider-Man documentary movie.

> Miles: Man, you really oversold this.
>
> Gunke: Just try to pay attention. **They literally show him figuring 
>   all his powers out**.

Spider-Man figured out all his powers by himself but Gunke says they are showing him how his powers work. So why did he give the opposite statement?

Comment: What?. You quote him saying that he figured his powers out, but then claim that the quote says something opposite. No, it literally says what you quoted.

Comment: This doesn't seem unclear to me. It seems to me that the question is based on a misunderstanding. This doesn't make the question close worthy. It might make it *downvote* worthy, but that's not the same as close worthy. A close vote is not a super downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you misunderstand that sentence.

"*They literally show him figuring all his powers out*" means that "they" (documentary makers) *show* (in the documentary) Spider-Man figuring all his powers out. If Gunke was saying they needed to show him how his powers work, then the sentence would instead be something like "*They literally show him **how to** figure all his powers out*".